# How to access SAP Cloud Neo Platform file system by putty on trial account?

Tags: sap-cloud-platform

I'm trying to access the SAP Neo cloud platform file system by using putty on trial account(**https://account.hanatrial.ondemand.com**) but not able to access.
Is there any way to achieve it on trial account ?

Answer (score 0):

The NEO services of the SAP Cloud Platform provide specific services with access methods suited to the service. For example for the SAP HANA database these access methods would be JDBC/ODBC and the Web-based development tools.

The NEO services don’t provide OS level access to the systems that provide the services.
In short: users don’t get direct file system or OS access.

Comment: Thanks for reply , If I wants to use the same feature in enterprise account at (https://account.hana.ondemand.com) will it work ?